# How to use fixed variable as title in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I need to use variable as a title for the graph in pandas. I have a csv file and from there I create multiple csv files as well graph according to the resource_id found in main csv file.

Sample content from my csv file:

```
Access_Stat_ID,Resource_ID,Range_Start,Range_End,Name,Format,Number,Matched_URL
6890859,10020,"2014-05-01 00:00:00","2014-05-31 23:59:59","May 2014","html",89,"/dissertationen/biologie/behrend-anke/HTML/behrend-vita.html"
6890860,10021,"2014-05-01 00:00:00","2014-05-31 23:59:59","May 2014","pdf",30,"/dissertationen/biologie/dreier-lars/PDF/Dreier.pdf"
6890861,10021,"2014-05-01 00:00:00","2014-05-31 23:59:59","May 2014","entry",2,"?"
6890862,10021,"2014-05-01 00:00:00","2014-05-31 23:59:59","May 2014","html",11,"/dissertationen/biologie/dreier-lars/HTML/chapter4.html"
```

This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dbo.Access_Stat_all.csv',error_bad_lines=False, usecols=['Range_Start','Format','Resource_ID','Number'])
uniquevalues = np.unique(df[['Resource_ID']].values)

for resource_id in uniquevalues:
    df1 = df[df['Resource_ID'] == resource_id]
    df1 = df1[['Format', 'Range_Start', 'Number']]
    #truncate the date to only take month and year
    df1["Range_Start"] = df1["Range_Start"].str[:7]
    df1 = df1.groupby(['Format', 'Range_Start'], as_index=True).last()
    pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
    df1 = df1.unstack()
    df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel()
    if df1.index.contains('entry'):
        df2 = df1[1:4].sum(axis=0)
    else:
        df2 = df1[0:3].sum(axis=0)
    df2.name = 'sum'
    df2 = df1.append(df2)
    df2.to_csv('csv_files/' + str(resource_id) + '.csv', sep="\t", float_format='%.f')
    if df2.index.contains('entry'):
        df3 = df2.T[['entry', 'sum']].copy()
    else:
        df3 = df2.T[['sum']].copy()

    # convert index to use pandas datetime format
    df3.index = pd.to_datetime(df3.index)

    # plot the data
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)

    # use matplotlib date formatters
    years = mdates.YearLocator()  # every year
    yearsFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')

    # format the major ticks
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)

    ax.plot(df3)
    ax.legend(["Seitenzugriffe", "Dateiabrufe"])
    plt.tight_layout()
    xtl = [item.get_text()[:4] for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
    ax.set_xticklabels(xtl)
    fig.savefig('plots/'+ str(resource_id) + '.png')
    plt.close('all')
```

Now in the plot/graph, I want the particular resource_id and range_start as the title. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you've defined `resource_id` in your `for` loop, right? So you can use it as a variable when you construct your plot:

```
plt.title(resource_id)
```

Each iteration of your for loop will result in a different title. With the dataset you've provided, in the first iteration, `resource_id` should equal `10020`, and then `10021`, and therefore two plots will be created / saved. Look through the [Matplotlib tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) for more examples of setting the title if you aren't clear.

Second, with regards to `"Range Start"`, subset your dataframe so it only contains the relevant `resource_id`, and then iterate through each `Range Start` value:

```
uniquevalues = np.unique(df[['Resource_ID']].values)

for resource_id in uniquevalues:
    df1 = df[df['Resource_ID'] == resource_id]
    df1 = df1[['Format', 'Range_Start', 'Number']]
    #truncate the date to only take month and year
    df1["Range_Start"] = df1["Range_Start"].str[:7]
    unique_range_starts = np.unique(df["Range Start"].values)
    for range_start in unique_range_start:
          # all your code to construct the graph goes here....
```

Now you have `resource_id` and `range_start` as variables for each plot title:

```
plt.title(resource_id + range_start)
```

Comment: I actually have different range_start. In the above given sample it is all same, yeah but for 1 resource id there is 1 range_start

Comment: @December Edited my answer. I misread your comment and thought there were multiple `range_start`s for each `resource_id`, but if there's only one, it's even easier and the code above should still apply, except you're only doing 1 iteration (since there's only 1 unique value of `range_start` for a given `resource_id`).

Comment: It must be another for loop, right? Now, if I want to include Range_End as well, another for loop? Doesn't it make the runtime extremely high? Even with only one for loop it takes me around an hour to fully compile :(

Comment: It does given all the nested for loops. But I'm assuming your `Range_Start` needs to be before your `Range_End` right? So you can add in a check (first convert them to dates, since they're strings right now) that `range_start` is before `range_end`- otherwise you can skip that iteration. That should help lower the runtime a bit. Also, is compile time or execution time an hour? Are you actually compiling this code into an executable?

Comment: OP has accepted the answer but I don't think your code does what op wanted. unique_range_starts = np.unique(df["Range Start"].values) takes all unique range_start but one resource_id has one unique range_start as op mentioned it.

Comment: @Uttam that's true- I noted in my comment a few lines above that starts with "Edited my answer" the code should still working though- it will only iterate once through the for loop, given that there is only one unique value. Is not that true?